# Application Insights failing with System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException on load - WP 8.1

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8.1, azure-application-insights

I am starting to explore Application Insights and tried adding it to my Windows Phone 8.1 app. While trying to execute the project, an exception is thrown on load within `Public Sub New()` in App.xaml.vb. The line where the error happens is

```
TelemetryClient = new TelemetryClient()
```

The exception thrown is

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Innerexception details:

> {System.InvalidOperationException: Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ComponentContextInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=0.16.1.418, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not implement the required interface
>
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.IContextInitializer.
>      at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.CreateInstance(Type interfaceType, String typeName)
>      at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadInstance(XElement definition, Type expectedType, Object instance)
>      at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadInstances[T](XElement definition, ICollection`1 instances)}

I followed the steps outlined [in the Azure documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-get-started/). What may I be doing wrong?

Comment: What was the `InnerException`? `TargetInvocationException` always has one. (It tells you what actually happened in the reflectively invoked method.) Seeing some other code in `New()` might also help us.

Comment: I have added the innerexception details for reference. As for other code within New(), this is the first line, followed by InitializeComponent()

Comment: Is your debugger set to break on first-chance exceptions? What happens if you just have execution continue after the exception is thrown?

Comment: I believe it is turned off, but I may be wrong. None of the 'Thrown' is checked in my debugger settings. If I continue, the app crashes without executing the next line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a corrupted solution. I had added the nuget and then added the Application Insights. In between I had upgraded the nugget package to the 0.16 pre-release version. In effect it had created multiple references. So I ended up manually clearing all entries of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights in package.config and .vbproj. I also removed all the references and referenced the whole thing again. Now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Windows Phone app on top of Windows Runtime or on top of Silverlight?

If you remove the following line from ApplicationInsights.config, does your app start successfully?

```
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ComponentContextInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"/>
```

Comment: Its a Runtime app. Removing the line makes no difference and it still crashes.

Comment: The latest NuGet is not using "using" anymore. Instead it adds: TelemetryClient = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient() 

So it seems like you are not using the latest. 

Can you try to start a new project and make sure you are installing this NuGet: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps/0.16.1-build00418

Comment: Yes. Having the latest version 0.16 build 418 pre-release from May 1, 2015. Still no luck and getting the same exception.

Comment: An update. One workaround that I found was to instantiate TelemetryClient twice, with the first one in a Try Catch block. I would like it clean without the need for two instantiations.

Comment: Can you share your project? I can't get a repro?